# Azure Active Directory B2C SAML Integration

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, salesforce, azure-ad-b2c

I'm following the official MS guide [Set up sign-in with a Salesforce SAML provider by using custom policies in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-sf-app-custom?tabs=applications). I have completed all the configuration but when I try to run the application I receive a strange error which states **Claim with id "userId" already exists in the claims collection**. 
I was searching for **userId** in my custom policies:

**TrustFrameworkBase.xml:** in this file **userid** is NOT declared, a claim called **issuerUserId** is declared in ClaimsSchema as datatype string and it is used in the following claim transformation:

```
<ClaimsTransformation Id="CreateAlternativeSecurityId" TransformationMethod="CreateAlternativeSecurityId">
        <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" TransformationClaimType="key" />
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" TransformationClaimType="identityProvider" />
        </InputClaims>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="alternativeSecurityId" TransformationClaimType="alternativeSecurityId" />
        </OutputClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation>
```

**issuerUserId** is then used in Facebook claim provider:

```
<ClaimsProvider>
    <Domain>facebook.com</Domain>
    <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="id" />
...
    </OutputClaims>
...
</ClaimsProvider>
```

**TrustFrameworkExtension.xml:** the claim **userid** is the output claim of the claim provider I'm using (salesforce):

```
<ClaimsProvider>
      <Domain>salesforce</Domain>
...
      <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="userid"/>
      </OutputClaims>
...
</ClaimsProvider>
```

**SignUpOrSigninSalesforce.xml:** the claim **userid** is the output claim of the relying party I'm using (salesforce):

```
<RelyingParty>
    <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpSignInSalesforce" />
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
    <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" />
        ...
      </OutputClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>
</RelyingParty>
```

Based on the error claim **userid** is defined twice, but I don't find a double definition, do you have any clue?

Thanks.

Comment: did you see your SAML assertion and there may be multiple claims with same attribute name.

Answer (score 1):

After 3 days of exhausting troubleshooting I have found five minutes ago the error. 
In my case I did not follow exactly microsoft steps, I wrongly changed **SignUpSignInSalesforce** UserJourney in the orchestration step 3 in **TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml**:

```
<UserJourney Id="SignUpSignInSalesforce">
....
    <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
              <ClaimsExchanges>
                <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="salesfoce" />
              </ClaimsExchanges>
            </OrchestrationStep>
...
</UserJourney>
```

The wrong value is **TechnicalProfileReferenceId**. When I changed the value from **salesforce** to **AAD-UserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId-NoError** the solution started working. 
What I have done it was re-reading the documentation of Microsoft step by step looking for mistakes.